# RecyclerView adds items multiple times

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use a `RecyclerView` with a `CardLayout` and the `CardLayout` contains multiple components. For filling the `RecyclerView` I use an `Adapter` but my problem is, that sometimes when I add new items the item is added multiple times into the `RecyclerView`. But it is no behavior which is always reproducible (so maybe it has to do with threading?).

I don't know the reason :/ I would be very glad for each hint or advice.

The code below is a "nearly" working TodoManager, the only problem is the one explained above.

My `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static String fileName = "todos.ser";

    private ArrayList<Todo> todos;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        updateTodos();
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(todos, getWindow());

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.todos);
        assert recyclerView != null;
        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        assert fab != null;
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                adapter.addTodo(new Todo(""), todos.size());
                int count = adapter.getItemCount();
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(count - 1);
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateTodos() {
        todos = new ArrayList<>();
        todos.add(new Todo(""));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        Log.i(TAG, "save todos=" + todos.size());
        // Save logic
    }
}
```

The `Todo`:

```
public class Todo implements Serializable {

    // The creationDate is not used at the moment
    private Date creationDate;
    private String description;
    private boolean isChecked;

    public Todo(String description) {
        this.description = description;
        this.creationDate = new Date();
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setIsChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }
}
```

The `RecyclerViewAdapter`:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.TodoViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

    private final List<Todo> todos;
    private final Window window;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Todo> todos, Window window) {
        this.todos = todos;
        this.window = window;
    }

    public class TodoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, TextWatcher {
        CheckBox cbDone;
        EditText tvDescription;
        FloatingActionButton btnDelete;

        public TodoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cbDone = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbDone);
            tvDescription = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            btnDelete = (FloatingActionButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

            tvDescription.addTextChangedListener(this);
            cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onClick called: remove todo.");
            removeTodo(getAdapterPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCheckedChanged called: isDone=" + isChecked);
            Todo todo = getTodo(getAdapterPosition());
            todo.setIsChecked(isChecked);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.i(TAG, "afterTextChanged called: text=" + s.toString());
            Todo todo = getTodo(getAdapterPosition());
            todo.setDescription(s.toString());
        }
    }

    public void addTodo(Todo todo, int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position > todos.size()) {
            Log.e(TAG, " add: index=" + position);
        } else {
            todos.add(position, todo);
            notifyItemInserted(position);
        }
    }

    public void removeTodo(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= todos.size()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "remove: index=" + position);
        } else {
            todos.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

    public Todo getTodo(int position) {
        Todo todo = null;
        if (position < 0 || position >= todos.size()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "get: index=" + position);
        } else {
            todo = todos.get(position);
        }
        return todo;
    }

    @Override
    public TodoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new TodoViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TodoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.cbDone.setChecked(todos.get(position).isChecked());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(todos.get(position).getDescription());

        if(holder.tvDescription.requestFocus()) {
            window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return todos.size();
    }
}
```

The `main_layout`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/todomanager"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_header_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/header_text_size"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_header_button"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/todos"
        android:layout_below="@id/header_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout for the `CardView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/todo"
    android:layout_below="@id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cbDone"
            android:hint="@string/insert_description"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_todo_text"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_todo_button"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The following code is needed for the styling:
`dimens.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="app_bar_height">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="text_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_header_text">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="header_text_size">24sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_header_button">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="padding_todo_text">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="margin_todo_button">10sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

`colors.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#212121</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#009688</color>
</resources>
```

`strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <string name="todomanager">Todos</string>
    <string name="insert_description">insert description ...</string>
</resources>
```

The following screenshots displays the wrong behavior. The left one is correct, the middle one is still correct but when there starts scrolling some entries are duplicated in the view.

[image: Correct behavior at the beginning]
[image: Still correct behavior]
[image: Here you can see, that some entries are duplicated in the list]

After some tests I discovered that these entries are the same entries, so when I click once on the delete of an entry all duplicated entries also disappear. And the problem starts whit scrolling as far as I have some entries out of view and I scroll around the displayed entries are duplicated.

I also discovered that it starts when I add the 12th element:

The logcat output before the 12th element was added:

```
I/MainActivity: fab.onClick count=[7]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text= position=[6]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=t position=[6]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=te position=[6]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=tes position=[6]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test position=[6]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test5 position=[6]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: addTodo position=[7] count=[7]
I/MainActivity: fab.onClick count=[8]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text= position=[7]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=t position=[7]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=te position=[7]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=tes position=[7]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test position=[7]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test6 position=[7]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: addTodo position=[8] count=[8]
I/MainActivity: fab.onClick count=[9]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text= position=[8]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=t position=[8]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=te position=[8]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=tes position=[8]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test position=[8]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test7 position=[8]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: addTodo position=[9] count=[9]
```

The first strange behavior starts when adding the 10th item, because there are `afterTextChanged` calls which should not be there and also the `GC` free:

```
I/MainActivity: fab.onClick count=[10]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text= position=[9]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=t position=[9]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=te position=[9]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=tes position=[9]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test position=[9]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test8 position=[9]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test3 position=[4]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test1 position=[2]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=training position=[1]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=work position=[0]
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 52541(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(52KB) LOS objects, 35% free, 28MB/44MB, paused 7.486ms total 62.227ms
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: addTodo position=[10] count=[10]
```

And when adding the 11th and 12th item the `afterTextChanged` calls explode and the strange behavior starts:

```
I/MainActivity: fab.onClick count=[11]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text= position=[10]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=t position=[10]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=te position=[10]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=tes position=[10]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test position=[10]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test9 position=[10]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test3 position=[4]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test1 position=[2]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=training position=[1]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=work position=[0]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=work position=[0]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test7 position=[8]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test9 position=[10]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=training position=[1]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: addTodo position=[11] count=[11]
I/MainActivity: fab.onClick count=[12]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text= position=[11]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=t position=[11]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=te position=[11]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=tes position=[11]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test position=[11]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test1 position=[11]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test10 position=[11]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test5 position=[6]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test3 position=[4]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test2 position=[3]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test1 position=[2]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=training position=[1]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=work position=[0]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=work position=[0]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=training position=[1]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=work position=[0]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test6 position=[7]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test8 position=[9]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test9 position=[10]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test10 position=[11]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test10 position=[11]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test9 position=[10]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test10 position=[11]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test4 position=[5]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test2 position=[3]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test1 position=[2]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=training position=[1]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=work position=[0]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=work position=[0]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=training position=[1]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=work position=[0]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=test1 position=[2]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=training position=[1]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=work position=[0]
I/RecyclerViewAdapter: afterTextChanged called: text=work position=[0]
```

Another strange behavior which I found is that my data is correct and when I go into the edit mode the data looks wrong and when I leave edit mode it looks okay again.

[image: expected entries]
[image: duplicated entries in edit mode]
[image: expected entries again]

Comment: Where are you calling updateTodos(); ? How are you getting new data which gets duplicated?

Comment: @ZahidRasheed The `updateTodos()` is only called once in the `onCreate()` of the `MainActivity`. There I load the data from a file (this code was removed otherwise the code would be much more large)

Comment: I would recommend looking into only that code. I have experience working with RecyclerViews and adapters and duplication never happens unless the adapter source is not correct.

Comment: @Zahid Rasheed this is my whole code only the persistence was removed and there was a load method in the `onCreate` and a store method in the `onStop`. The Adapter is 1:1 the same  code from me

Comment: try to log the position in and `fab.onClick()` and the adapter `addTodo()` . The only place to add the data in recyclerview is through the method `addTodo()`as per your code. The `logcat` might give some insight.

Comment: @user2560050 I updated my question a lot

Comment: The duplicated views can be wrong from incorrect data o due to not updated viewholder. It seems that it is the first case, however you can see the second case behaviour when scrolling because the views' order change.

Comment: @LeiNaD_87 I don't think that it has to do with the data because always when I stop the application the `todos` are saved and there the count is displayed and it is exactly the count of the added items. So I think it has to do with the displaying from the `RecyclerView` because when I load the items there is always the correct number in the log (same as stored) but the displaying starts to fail when I scroll.

Comment: @LeiNaD_87  I recognized that it depends on the phone

Comment: @user2560050 I recognized that it depends on the phone

Comment: @ZahidRasheed I recognized that it depends on the phone

Comment: just my wild guess. one of the possible reason (which I have encountered) is you start adding the same data into recycler view when you perform some action ( in your case is when you start scrolling). Check if you start adding duplicate data into the recycler view and if you need to clean and regenerate your recycler view

Comment: @JamesYTL I cannot update the `RecyclerView`on each `scroll` because of performance etc. I am not adding any element at `onScrolled`. I checked the `ItemCount` from the `RecyclerViewAdapter` on each scroll and it stays like expected on the same count :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `onBindViewHolder` method the focus was set, so when I remove the focus code it works.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TodoViewHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.cbDone.setChecked(todos.get(position).isChecked());
     holder.tvDescription.setText(todos.get(position).getDescription());

     // Remove the following code
     // if(holder.tvDescription.requestFocus()) {
     //    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
     // }
}
```

Comment: Hey I haven't set any focus in onBindHolder; still facing the same issue.But all the duplicate entries disappear I press back and open that fragment again.

Comment: same here I've experienced the same problem.