# RecyclerView different behaviors on different phones

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-nexus

I have got an app which uses a `RecyclerView`. This app has a different behavior depending on the phone. On the first phone `Google Nexus 6P` there it behaves wrong and I created a question: [RecyclerView adds items multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362885/recyclerview-adds-items-multiple-times?noredirect=1#comment64148932_38362885)
On the other phone `Samsung Edge 6` it works correct.

So can you please give me any advice how to handle this different behavior? (E.g. write a bug ticket or what should be done in this case).

Comment: Which answer do you expect to this question, that would not much better fit to the other one?

Comment: @Henry Should the problem be reported or how to handle such a problem?

Comment: There is no chance that there is actually something wrong with the `RecyclerView`. Especially since it doesn't work on the 6P, but it does on the Edge.  Trust me: the problem is your code and not the RecyclerView. And if it really works on the edge then there are only two different explanations: Either the problem with your code is timing based and the different hardware on those two phones causes one phone to experience the problem and the other one does not our more likely Samsung - like they always do - messed something up and implemented something off spec that by accident fixes you error.

Comment: My point is: show us the relevant parts of your code, otherwise noone can help you.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I added the important parts to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362885/recyclerview-adds-items-multiple-times?noredirect=1#comment64148932_38362885

Comment: Maybe you did. But I don't care about other questions, I am looking at this one, and there is no code here. If you have a new and different question to your previous one then ask it properly, it doesn't matter that both questions are related. Each question has to be complete and answerable on its own and for that it has to contain all the relevant information.

Comment: @XaverKapeller this question has to do with the operational stuff. Should a bug ticket been written or something like that etc. I dont want to copy the code 1:1 because it is a different question.

Comment: I have looked at your other question and I can say: You have a problem with view recycling. or to be more accurate you are causing problems for view recycling.

Comment: The weird logic in your listeners is probably causing this. Debug your code. Follow every step and you are going to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @XaverKapeller what listener logic do you mean with weird?